# Issues getting DOCK_STATE on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sdk

Following this article: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

All I'm trying to get is whether or not the dock state of the phone is a 0 or a 2. The code I have right now throws a null pointer exception at dockState. All the app does at the moment is load up an activity without "setContentView" and execute the following code.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
Intent dockStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int dockState = dockStatus.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE, 0);
```

Despite whether or not it's in car dock mode it throws a null pointer. According to the sdk doc, I should be able to get this pretty simply.

Comment: I know it has been long, but did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer occurs because the Intent itself is `null`, therefore you can't get the extras.

The docking stuff is part of the Battery Intent (for me, this seems to be a bug an Android).

This will work (the code works, but my device doesn't support docks, so i'm unable to tell if it really works or always returns "undocked"):

```
  IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
  // Read docking state
  int dockState = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE, -1);
  boolean isDocked = true;
  if (dockState == Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED) {
     isDocked = false;
  }
```

Comment: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED = Broadcast Action: Indicates low battery condition on the device. This broadcast corresponds to the "Low battery warning" system dialog. This relates to docking how exactly?

Comment: Ups, sorry for the mistake. Answer can be deleted.